# What's the difference between a catalog and a schema in a relational database?

Tags: database, schema, catalog

I used to think schema were the "upper wrapper" object before the database itself.
I mean `DB.schema.<what_ever_object_name_under_schema>`.

Well, the catalog "wrapper" is now quite confusing. Why should we need a catalog? For what purpose, precisely should the catalog be used?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

From the relational point of view :

> The catalog is the place where--among other things--all of the various schemas (external, conceptual, internal) and all of the corresponding mappings (external/conceptual, conceptual/internal) are kept.
>
> In other words, the catalog contains detailed information (sometimes called **descriptor information** or **metadata**) regarding the various objects that are of interest to the system itself.
>
> For example, the optimizer uses catalog information about indexes and other physical storage structures, as well as much other information, to help it decide how to implement user requests. Likewise, the security subsystem uses catalog information about users and security constraints to grant or deny such requests in the first place.

An Introduction to Database Systems, 7th ed., C.J. Date, p 69-70.

---

From the SQL standard point of view :

> Catalogs are named collections of schemas in an SQL-environment. An
>   SQL-environment contains zero or more catalogs. A catalog contains
>   one or more schemas, but always contains a schema named
>   INFORMATION_SCHEMA that contains the views and domains of the
>   Information Schema.

[Database Language SQL](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt), (Proposed revised text of DIS 9075), p 45

---

From the SQL point of view :

> A catalog is often synonymous with *database*. In most SQL dbms, if you query the information_schema views, you'll find that values in the "table_catalog" column map to the name of a database.
>
> If you find your platform using *catalog* in a broader way than any of these three definitions, it might be referring to something broader than a database--a database cluster, a server, or a server cluster. But I kind of doubt that, since you'd have found that easily in your platform's documentation.

Answer (score 262):

[Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/562459/mike-sherrill-cat-recall) gave [an excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7023159/642706). I'll add simply one example: [Postgres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL).

## Cluster = A Postgres Installation

When you install Postgres on a machine, that installation is called a *cluster*. ‘Cluster’ here is not meant in the [hardware sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster) of multiple computers working together. In Postgres, *cluster* refers to the fact that you can have multiple unrelated databases all up and running using the same Postgres server engine.

The word *cluster* is also defined by the [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) [Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92) in the same way as in Postgres. Closely following the SQL Standard is a primary goal of the Postgres project.

The [SQL-92](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92) specification says:

> A cluster is an implementation-defined collection of catalogs.

and

> Exactly one cluster is associated with an SQL-session

That's an obtuse way of saying a cluster is a database server (each catalog is a database).

## Cluster > Catalog > Schema > Table > Columns & Rows

So in both Postgres and the SQL Standard we have this containment hierarchy:

- A computer may have one cluster or multiple.
- A database server is a *cluster*.
- A cluster has [*catalogs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_catalog). ( Catalog = Database )
- Catalogs have *[schemas](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html)*. (Schema = [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) of tables, and security boundary)
- Schemas have [*tables*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_(database)).
- Tables have [*rows*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_(database)).
- Rows have *values*, defined by [*columns*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_(database)).
  Those values are the business data your apps and users care about such as person's name, invoice due date, product price, gamer’s high score. The column defines the [data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type) of the values (text, date, number, and so on).

[image: Diagram showing nesting boxes representing how connecting on a port gets you to cluster (a database server) which contains one or more Catalogs (a database) each of which contains one or more Schemas (a namespace) each of which contains tables each of which has rows.]

### Multiple Clusters

This diagram represents a single cluster. In the case of Postgres, you can have more than one cluster per host computer (or virtual OS). Multiple clusters is commonly done, for testing and deploying new versions of Postgres (ex: [9.0](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.0), [9.1](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.1), [9.2](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.2), [9.3](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.3), [9.4](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.4), [9.5](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5)).

If you did have multiple clusters, imagine the diagram above duplicated.

Different port numbers allow the multiple clusters to live side-by-side all up and running at the same time. Each cluster would be assigned its own port number. The usual `5432` is only the default, and can be set by you. Each cluster is listening on its own assigned port for incoming database connections.

## Example Scenario

For example, a company could have two different software development teams. One writes software to manage the warehouses while the other team builds software to manage sales and marketing. Each dev team has their own database, blissfully unaware of the other’s.

But the IT operations team took a decision to run both databases on a single computer box (Linux, Mac, whatever). So on that box they installed Postgres. So one database server (database cluster). In that cluster, they create two catalogs, a catalog for each dev team: one named 'warehouse' and one named 'sales'.

Each dev team uses many dozens of tables with different purposes and access roles. So each dev team organizes their tables into schemas. By coincidence, both dev teams do some tracking of accounting data, so each team happens to have a schema named 'accounting'. Using the same schema name is not a problem because the catalogs each have their own [namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) so no collision.

Furthermore, each team eventually creates a table for accounting purposes named 'ledger'. Again, no naming collision.

You can think of this example as a hierarchy…

- Computer (hardware box or virtualized server)

  - `Postgres 9.2` cluster (installation)

    - `warehouse` catalog (database)

      - `inventory` schema

        - [… some tables]
      - `accounting` schema

        - `ledger` table
        - [… some other tables]
    - `sales` catalog (database)

      - `selling` schema

        - [… some tables]
      - `accounting` schema (coincidental same name as above)

        - `ledger` table (coincidental same name as above)
        - [… some other tables]
  - `Postgres 9.3` cluster

    - [… other schemas & tables]

Each dev team's software makes a connection to the cluster. When doing so, they must specify which catalog (database) is theirs. Postgres requires that you connect to one catalog, but you are not limited to that catalog. That initial catalog is merely a default, used when your SQL statements omit the name of a catalog.

So if the dev team ever needs to access the other team's tables, they may do so *if* the database administrator has given them [privileges](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-priv.html) to do so. Access is made with explicit naming in the pattern: **catalog.schema.table**. So if the 'warehouse' team needs to see the other team’s ('sales' team) ledger, they write SQL statements with `sales.accounting.ledger`. To access their own ledger, they merely write `accounting.ledger`. If they access both ledgers in the same piece of source code, they may choose to avoid confusion by including their own (optional) catalog name, `warehouse.accounting.ledger` versus `sales.accounting.ledger`.

---

By the way…

You may hear the word *schema* used in a more general sense, meaning the entire design of a particular database's table structure. By contrast, in the SQL Standard the word means specifically the particular layer in the `Cluster > Catalog > Schema > Table` hierarchy.

Postgres uses both the word *database* as well as *catalog* in various places such as the [CREATE DATABASE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/sql-createdatabase.html) command.

Not all database system provides this full hierarchy of `Cluster > Catalog > Schema > Table`. Some have only a single catalog (database). Some have no schema, just one set of tables. Postgres is an exceptionally powerful product.

Comment: If it's `...Catalog > Schema...` , can someone tell me why "Catalog" and "Schema" nodes in pgAdmin (PostgreSQL UI) are sibling nodes, instead of Schema node as a child node of Catalog?

Comment: That "Schema" node is yours, but the "Catalogs" node is not. The "Catalogs" node has exactly two items: (1) `PostgreSQL (pg_catalog)`, the system catalog, the dozens of "pg_" tables that store the metadata definitions of your databases, such as `pg_index`,  `pg_trigger`, and `pg_constraint`. (2) `ANSI (information_schema)`, the read-only view of that same system catalog defined by the SQL standard as  [`information_schema`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema). A better name for the "Catalogs" node in pgAdmin might be "System" or "System Tables".

Comment: Thanks. "Not all database system provides this full hierarchy of Cluster > Catalog > Schema > Table. " I wonder what it is like for mysql, and SQL Server?

Comment: +1. Does all the tables in a schema have the same relational schema (i.e. the same set of attributes, and/or the same set of constraints)? Could you also see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48232448/what-do-schema-and-catalog-mean? Thanks.

Comment: @Tim A **schema is just a namespace** separating groups of tables, like folders are a namespace organizing files in a file system (except no nesting of schemas). Tables store your app’s data as attributes/columns by row.

Comment: Thanks. Could you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50882949/is-pg-user-a-view-or-a-catalog?

Comment: @Tim The [Answer by jjanes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50883279/642706) appears to be correct as far as I know. The computer industry is quite sloppy about using, re-using, and abusing terminology. You must consider the context to grasp the terms. Your Question there is a particularly frustrating example. The Postgres project is completely open in both source code and documentation. They welcome contributions. So if you feel strongly enough, rewrite that doc and submit your changes.

Comment: What about pgAdmin where I can see a catalog inside a database? like here: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/_images/main_left_pane.png

Comment: @mFeinstein See first Comment on this Answer. PgAdmin made funky choices in the terminology used in their user-interface.

Comment: So `information_schema` and `pg_catalog` are not catalogs at all but just special schemas?  Even though the PG documentation uses the term "System Catalogs"?

Comment: @Andy When in doubt, read the documentation: [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-schema.html) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-schemas.html) for starters.