# How to get database schema name when using oracle jdbc connection?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to get all db tables using DatabaseMetaData.getTables() method. But this method requires database schema name pattern. Is it possible to get schema name for current db connection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard schema for your current connection is the name of the user you use to log in. So if your user is `SCOTT` you have to use `SCOTT` for `DatabaseMetaData.getTables()`.

You can obtain the username through `DatabaseMetaData.getUserName()`.

But remember that the comparison of schema/username done in the JDBC driver is case-sensititve and normally usernames are in uppercase.

I am not 100% sure if `DatabaseMetaData.getUserName()` will return the name in the correct case in all situations. To be sure, you might want to do an upperCase() before using that value.

Comment: You're right. String with schema id name i am looking for is an upper case username string.

Comment: Since schema/username is case-sensitive, why Oracle stores the username in uppercase??

Comment: @CKLee: because the SQL standard requires identifiers to be folded to uppercase, that's why non-quoted identifiers are stored in uppercase in Oracle. The case-sensitivity in this case comes from the fact that the JDBC driver in the background does something like `where owner = ?` and *that* comparison is case sensitive (as every other string comparison). The username as part of an *identifier* is not case sensitive. `select * from SCOTT.foobar` is identicial to `select * from scott.FOObar`

Comment: I am now working on DDL layer for different databases. The Oracle behavior make me can't generalize my implementation. Anyway to force Oracle to store username with original case?

Comment: @CKLee: there is no single solution to this: some DBMS store it in uppercase, some in lowercase, some in mixed-case. Some are case-sensitive when comparing strings, some are not, some are sometimes. Some always work the same independently of the operating system and installation options, for some this behavior depends on the configuration or the operating system.

Comment: Just tested `DatabaseMetaData.getUserName()` returns uppercase for Oracle.

Comment: `OracleDataSource.getUser()` return original case.

Comment: Yea this works, but why can't I simply call connection.getSchema()?  In my environment it throws a NPE.  Aces Oracle!  Just a real nice job.

Comment: Unfortunately there seems to be no consistency between databases (Oracle, MySQL, etc) in testing. MySQL gives the actual username@host and [connection].getSchema() returns null, even when set on properties for database instance ID (SID in Oracle parlance).

Comment: @DarrellTeague: that's because MySQL does not distinguish between "database" and "schema". They only have databases (but use them like schemas). As they _call_ it "database" the JDBC driver exposes that as a "catalog" (which is the equivalent of a "database" in the SQL standard and JDBC). So to call `getTables()` for MySQL (which this question and answer is **not** about) you need to provide the correct _catalog_, not a schema. But that is completely unrelated to initial question. My answer is only valid for **Oracle** not for any other DBMS.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Given the nature of the forum as an educational and answer source ... it seems wholly appropriate to broach the topic of JDBC in general. This was a comment versus an answer in any case.  The provided answer lends to the argument that the JDBC implementation is mismatched between at least two major vendors - namely the answer being to use an incorrectly named method (getUserName) to retrieve the requested "schema" name (for which there is a getSchemaName() method). Lastly, all databases support a 1-to-many relationship between database names/schemas and users.

Comment: @DarrellTeague:  Oracle does not support a 1-to-may relationship between users and schemas  and thus `getUserName()` **will** return the schema. Additionally: there is no `getSchemaName()` method in `DatabaseMetaData`. And for the "schema" argument of `getTables()` the username is the appropriate information to pass in Oracle. (and `Connection.getSchema()` was not supported back in 2012 when I wrote the answer)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Java 7 (release date 2011) has Connection.getSchema(). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getSchema() and... yes there can be many different users in Oracle for the same DB, with access to the same schema. Granted the schema will be "owned" by only one of those users but with privileges, Joe could access the Sally.Table (in Sally schema). Thus connection made by Joe referencing Sally schema objects. In such case, getUserName() for Joe would not resolve to the Sally schema.

Comment: @DarrellTeague: good luck trying `Connection.getSchema()` with an Oracle 11 driver (which was the only one available when I wrote the answer). Feel free to write a new answer which reflects the new situation 6 years later

Answer (score 3):

Try to play with getCatalogs(). This is a quick draft

```
  public List<String> getDatabases(DBEnv dbEnv) {

        Connection conn = getConnection(dbEnv);
        List<String> resultSet = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            DatabaseMetaData metaData = conn.getMetaData();
            ResultSet res = metaData.getCatalogs();

            while (res.next()) {
                resultSet.add(res.getString("TABLE_CAT"));
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error(e.toString());
        }

        return resultSet;

    }
```

Comment: Don't know why but the result set is empty.

Comment: @ThaiTran Do you have any idea of why the method is called _getCatalogs_ and not _getSchemas_ ?

Comment: @johnny-b-goode - if you found out why in the meanwhile :) - it was the DB that was interpreting the method differently ? I mean, it works on MySql, but on Oracle or other type of DB it may return other types of objects (I came across this hint while reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942520/relationship-between-catalog-schema-user-and-database-instance)

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 7, `Connection` has a `getSchema` method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getSchema--

Comment: Good call but... on at least MySQL (v5.7.x) [Connection].getSchema() returns null - even though the schema was defined on the connection string. MySQL interprets this a bit differently as a database instance ID and does not apparently translate this into the appropriate data model for JDBC (catalog/schema/{object}).

Comment: The OP question was specifically related to Oracle but given that JDBC is supposed to be abstract ... one would think "getSchema()" would return the schema and "getUserName()" et al would return the expected data associated with a common model of users, database instance IDs and schemas but... alas this is apparently not consistent for Oracle nor MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

The answer unfortunately is that there are no consistent solutions. If John has access to Sally.Table ... the query will work but getUserName() will return John and not Sally schema. For Oracle the user owns their schema and while others may have access, that user ID is the *default* schema on that connection.

Further, neither getSchemaName() nor getCatalog() will return the schema name.

@horse_with_no_name has the closest answer for Oracle since a given user name is the (default) schema name unless overridden in object reference as shown.

For other databases the same rules do not apply consistently.

Answer (score 1):

You can get schema name using

```
Connection conn = 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:port:SID",prop);    
DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = conn.getMetaData();
System.out.println("schema name >>>> "+databaseMetaData.getUserName());
```