# why database name in hbm file overrides database name in hibernate configuration file

Tags: hibernate

In my hibernate configuration file i used to specify the properties including the database name

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
```

in one of the hbm files

```
<class name="com.test.entity.User" table="user" catalog="employee">
```

Why the catalog in hbm files overrides the connection to the database specified in the hibernate configuration file hibernate ?

Does it connect to both databases?

Answer (score 0):

The entity-level configuration overrides the default one because you might want to have a default catalog for most of your entities while only a few of those should be used against a different catalog.

Anyway the global catalog settings is:

```
<prop key="hibernate.default_catalog">employee</prop>
```

But in MySql, [there's no difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942520/relationship-between-catalog-schema-user-and-database-instance) between the database name in the JDBC URL and the database catalog object.

In your example, the User entity will use the employee **catalog** and not the **test** one.