# Eclipse Data Source Explorer Does Not See MySql Schemas

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jpa

I configured a connection profile and I could ping it successfully, but the Data Source Explorer does not see any of the schemas (databases) in MySQL.

When I configure the connection for JPA, the database-specific validations fail and none of my TABLE names mapped to my entities are seen, and cause the failures.

I looked at previous questions and answers, and followed the suggestions, which allowed me to configure the connection successfully, but the explorer still does not see schemas.

Help would be greatly appreciated. I’ve burned a full day on this issue and I cannot find any answers from uncle Google.

The MySQL driver is configured correctly (otherwise the ping would fail).

URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/finances
Database Name: finances
Driver Class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
The driver Jar is attached and visible in the driver JAR list.

The JPA properties of the project point at the same connection as the Data Source Explore and the "connect" button connects successfully, the status bar at bottom of the window shows MyConnectionProfile (Connected).

The JPA properties are:

Platform: EclipseLink 2.5.x
User Library: EclipseLink 2.5.2
JPA Version: 2.1

The database-specific validation errors are

Table "XXXXX" cannot be resolved, for each of 15 tables.

I wanted to embed snapshots but I did not know how.

My very first question on SO! Be Gentle!

Comment: Dali is the Eclipse JPA tooling plug-in and is what validates your JPA mappings against the database. Dali depends on the Eclipse DTP plug-in, which provides connectivity to various databases. You are discovering one of the long-running issues with DTP: it handles MySQL a bit differently than it does all the other databases. (One of the challenges of Open Source. :-) One limitation is that the MySQL driver will list only a single schema per database. Are you specifying a schema in your JPA mappings?

Comment: Not that MySQL is the only one that is "different", they all have their quirks. Just that MySQL has one with schema/catalog and what they resemble. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942520/relationship-between-catalog-schema-user-and-database-instance