# Why flyway did not create a table?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, flyway

I recently work with flyway in springboot and I have such a question. Why flyway did not create a database? I just added a flyway dependency to my build.gradle, which now looks like this.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-orm:5.1.5.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.hibernate.search:hibernate-search-backend-lucene:6.0.0.Beta1'
    implementation 'org.hibernate.search:hibernate-search-mapper-orm:6.0.0.Beta1'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5'

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc', version: '2.1.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'com.vividsolutions', name: 'jts', version: '1.13'
    compile('org.flywaydb:flyway-core:6.0.6')
}
```

I configured data source like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:hibernate.properties")
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/geo_test");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("postgres");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("root");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.test.hibernate.domain");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.POOL_SIZE, env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection_pool_size"));
        properties.put("hibernate.search.default_backend", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.search.default_backend"));
        properties.put("hibernate.search.backends.myBackend.type", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.search.backends.myBackend.type"));
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_AUTO, env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        return properties;
    }
}
```

And here is my hibernate.properties:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresPlusDialect
hibernate.search.default_backend=myBackend
hibernate.search.backends.myBackend.type=lucene
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.connection_pool_size=1
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
```

And migration file which located in resources/db/migration:

```
create sequence hibernate_sequence start 1 increment 1;

create table geo_table (
    point_id int8 not null,
    latitude float8 not null,
    longitude float8 not null,

    primary key (point_id)
);
```

So, now I have next error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'searchServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/test/hibernate/config/HibernateConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [geo_table]
```

**upd:** application.properties:

```
spring.flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/geo_test
spring.flyway.schemas=public
spring.flyway.user=postgres
spring.flyway.password=root
spring.flyway.baseline-version=1
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration
spring.flyway.enabled=true
```

What's can be a problem? Should I configured datasource in application.properties? Or how it can be fixed?

Comment: What is your migration file called?

Comment: V20191018154653__Init_DB.sql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a database with flyway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791019/how-to-create-a-database-with-flyway)

Answer (score 1):

Flyway is expecting there to be an existing database for you to run your migration on.  Try creating the database, add the datasource url, username and password.  Then rerun your app and the geo_table will be created for you.

Comment: I'm very confused. Your question says "Why flyway did not create a database?" and now your comment says "Database already created."  Which one is it?

Comment: Sorry, I mean flyway did not create a table)

Comment: In your application logs, do you have any logs from `DbMigrate` before the `Hibernate` logs start?  I'm not familiar with Gradle so it is hard for me to tell if you have that flyway dependency configured correctly.

Comment: Everything fine if I remove d this line `sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.test.geolocation.hibernate.domain");` but in this case hibernate did not see my entities

Comment: You don't need that `HibernateConfig` config class. You should be able to let Spring Boot do all that initialization.  If your application has `@SpringBootApplication` then it will automatically scan for those entity files.

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-tests/spring-boot-smoke-tests/spring-boot-smoke-test-flyway and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-tests/spring-boot-smoke-tests/spring-boot-smoke-test-jpa