# Postgresql tables exists, but getting "relation does not exist" when querying

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgresql db with a number of tables. If I query:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name="my_table";
```

I will get a list of the columns returned properly.

However, when I query:

```
SELECT *
FROM "my_table";
```

I get the error:

```
(ProgrammingError) relation "my_table" does not exist
'SELECT *\n    FROM "my_table"\n' {}
```

Any thoughts on why I can get the columns, but can't query the table? Goal is to be able to query the table.

Comment: can you do the same with another table? try creating a new one.

Comment: The query you have shown can't work. `WHERE table_name="my_table";` is invalid because `"my_table"` references a column name and there is no such column in `information_schema.columns`. Please [edit] your question and add the **exact** `create table` statement you used to create the table.

Comment: do check this one https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192897/postgres-relation-does-not-exist-error

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You have to include the schema if isnt a public one

```
SELECT *
FROM <schema>."my_table"
```

Or you can change your default schema

```
SHOW search_path;
SET search_path TO my_schema;
```

Check your table schema here

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns
```

[image]

For example if a table is on the default schema `public` both this will works ok

```
SELECT * FROM parroquias_region
SELECT * FROM public.parroquias_region
```

But sectors need specify the schema

```
SELECT * FROM map_update.sectores_point
```

Comment: Correct answer. If not familiar with the SQL standard’s hierarchy of Cluster > Catalog > Schema > Table, see the Question, [What's the difference between a catalog and a schema in a relational database?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7022755/642706) and [my diagram](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FqyMq.png).

Comment: Yup - this did it, thanks much. Of course now I'm getting `permission denied`, but that at least I know where to go with.

Comment: For future readers of this thread, this error could also occur, like it did in my case, when the Schema name & Table name have mixed case characters & are not enclosed individually in double quotes. In other words they have to be specified as: "my_Schema"."my_Table"

Comment: @SnidhiSofpro Well that also happen with field names, My suggestion just use lower case names so you don't have to add the hassle of double quotes.

Comment: What if everything works with `SET search_path TO my_schema;` in postgres shell but the exact thing wont work in python code? I dont have any case sensitive problems. I'm sure!

Comment: @SnidhiSofpro comment was the solution for me.  Key sentence from what they referenced "Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted names are always folded to lower case"

Answer (score 67):

You can try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM public."my_table"
```

Don't forget double quotes near my_table.

Comment: Adding double quotes to the table name worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me. But why did it work with the double quotes and not without it?

Answer (score 25):

I had to include double quotes with the table name.

```
db=> \d
                           List of relations
 Schema |                     Name                      | Type  | Owner 
--------+-----------------------------------------------+-------+-------
 public | COMMONDATA_NWCG_AGENCIES                      | table | dan
 ...

db=> \d COMMONDATA_NWCG_AGENCIES
Did not find any relation named "COMMONDATA_NWCG_AGENCIES".
```

???

Double quotes:

```
db=> \d "COMMONDATA_NWCG_AGENCIES"
                         Table "public.COMMONDATA_NWCG_AGENCIES"
          Column          |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 ID                       | integer                     |           | not null | 
 ...
```

Lots and lots of double quotes:

```
db=> select ID from COMMONDATA_NWCG_AGENCIES limit 1;
ERROR:  relation "commondata_nwcg_agencies" does not exist
LINE 1: select ID from COMMONDATA_NWCG_AGENCIES limit 1;
                       ^
db=> select ID from "COMMONDATA_NWCG_AGENCIES" limit 1;
ERROR:  column "id" does not exist
LINE 1: select ID from "COMMONDATA_NWCG_AGENCIES" limit 1;
               ^
db=> select "ID" from "COMMONDATA_NWCG_AGENCIES" limit 1;
 ID 
----
  1
(1 row)
```

This is postgres 11.  The CREATE TABLE statements from this dump had double quotes as well:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "COMMONDATA_NWCG_AGENCIES";

CREATE TABLE "COMMONDATA_NWCG_AGENCIES" (
...
```

Comment: Postgres by default converts everything to lowercase unless of course double quotes are used.

Answer (score 25):

I hit this error and it turned out my connection string was pointing to another database, obviously the table didn't exist there.

I spent a few hours on this and no one else has mentioned to **double check your connection string**.

Comment: this is it for me. check you have set the correct database in your connection properties. that you can see the table does not mean it's correctly set.

Comment: This fixed an error I have. I had mistyped a DB name in foreign data server configuration where I tried to find my table.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem that occurred after I restored data from a postgres dumped db.

My dump file had the command below from where things started going south.

```sql
    SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
```

Solutions:

1. Probably remove it or change that `false` to be `true`.
2. Create a private schema that will be used to access all the tables.

The command above simply deactivates all the publicly accessible schemas.

Check more on the documentation here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/ecpg-connect.html

Answer (score 4):

The error can be caused by access restrictions. Solution:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE my_database TO my_user;
```

Answer (score 3):

I was using pgAdmin to create my tables and while I was not using reserved words, the generated table had a quote in the name and a couple of columns had quotes in them.  Here is an example of the generated SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE public."Test"
(
    id serial NOT NULL,
    data text NOT NULL,
    updater character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    "updateDt" time with time zone NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT test_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public."Test"
    OWNER to svc_newnews_app;
```

All of these quotes were inserted at "random".  I just needed to drop and re-create the table again without the quotes.

Tested on pgAdmin 4.26

Answer (score 3):

Please ensure that:

1. Your password is non-empty
2. In case it is empty, do not pass the `password` param in the connection string

This is one of the most common errors when starting out with the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Keep all your table names in lower case because when you rollback and then go to latest, it's looking for lowercase apparently.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the dump file I restored had these commands.

```
CREATE SCHEMA employees;
SET search_path = employees, pg_catalog;
```

I've commented those and restored again. The issue got resolved

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we have database name as `students` and schema name as `studentinformation` then to use all the table of this schema we need to set the path first which we can do in `postgresql` like:

```
client.connect()
.then(()=>console.log("connected succesfully"))
.then(()=>client.query("set search_path to students"))
.then(()=>client.query("show search_path"))
.then(()=>client.query("set search_path to studentinformation"))
.then(()=>client.query("show search_path"))
.then(results => console.table(results.rows)) //setting the search path
```

Answer (score -1):

I was using psql from PostgreSQL, and somehow I created the table in the "postgres=#" directory instead of first connecting to the database and creating it there.

So make sure that you connected to the database you want before creating tables