# postgres table does not exist, but actually it does

Tags: sql, postgresql, quoted-identifier

I am facing problem similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753568/postgresql-tables-exists-but-getting-relation-does-not-exist-when-querying),

I have restored this database from a dump.

Here is my problem,

```
test_api=# \d+
                                      List of relations
 Schema |             Name              |   Type   |     Owner     |    Size    | Description
--------+-------------------------------+----------+---------------+------------+-------------
 public | vehiclenumber                 | table    | luvpreetsingh | 8192 bytes |
 public | vehiclenumber_id_seq          | sequence | luvpreetsingh | 8192 bytes |
 public | launchPad_pair                | table    | luvpreetsingh | 8192 bytes |
```

All tables are in public schema(I have posted only relevant tables here). I am able to query from `vehiclenumber` table.

```
test_api=# select * from iot_vehiclenumber;
 id |  vn  | rk  |  rt   | seed | vt
----+------+-----+-------+------+----
  1 | 4513 | NO  | RESET | 1234 | 01
  2 | 1234 | YES | RESET | 1234 | 01
(2 rows)
```

But I am not able to query from `launchPad_pair` table.

```
test_api=# select * from launchPad_pair;
ERROR:  relation "launchpad_pair" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from launchPad_pair;

test_api=# select * from public.launchPad_pair;
ERROR:  relation "public.launchpad_pair" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from public.launchPad_pair;
```

I run the following query and it spits out all the info(again to make sure the schema is public),

```
test_api=# SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns where table_name='launchPad_pair';
 table_catalog | table_schema |   table_name   | column_name | ordinal_position |                column_default                 | is_nullable | data_type | character_maximum_length | character_octet_length | numeric_precision | numeric_precision_radix | numeric_scale | datetime_precision | interval_type | interval_precision | character_set_catalog | character_set_schema | character_set_name | collation_catalog | collation_schema | collation_name | domain_catalog | domain_schema | domain_name | udt_catalog  | udt_schema | udt_name | scope_catalog | scope_schema | scope_name | maximum_cardinality | dtd_identifier | is_self_referencing | is_identity | identity_generation | identity_start | identity_increment | identity_maximum | identity_minimum | identity_cycle | is_generated | generation_expression | is_updatable
---------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------+-------------+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+---------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+------------+----------+---------------+--------------+------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------
     test_api  | public       | launchPad_pair | id          |                1 | nextval('"launchPad_pairs_id_seq"'::regclass) | NO          | integer   |                          |                        |                32 |                       2 |             0 |                    |               |                    |                       |                      |                    |                   |                  |                |                |               |             | test_api | pg_catalog | int4     |               |              |            |                     | 1              | NO                  | NO          |                     |                |                    |                  |                  | NO             | NEVER        |                       | YES
     test_api  | public       | launchPad_pair | vehicle_id  |                2 |                                               | NO          | integer   |                          |                        |                32 |                       2 |             0 |                    |               |                    |                       |                      |                    |                   |                  |                |                |               |             | test_api | pg_catalog | int4     |               |              |            |                     | 2              | NO                  | NO          |                     |                |                    |                  |                  | NO             | NEVER        |                       | YES
     test_api  | public       | launchPad_pair | Box_id      |                3 |                                               | NO          | integer   |                          |                        |                32 |                       2 |             0 |                    |               |                    |                       |                      |                    |                   |                  |                |                |               |             | test_api | pg_catalog | int4     |               |              |            |                     | 3              | NO                  | NO          |                     |                |                    |                  |                  | NO             | NEVER        |                       | YES
```

I have checked many times to make sure there is no typo.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Turns out the tables were made using django models. The tables were not defined for the model using `class Meta`, so the table was named `"launchPad_pair"` instead `launchPad_pair`, which are 2 different things in postgres.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: Had the same issue, our db was setup with SQLAlchemy.  Pulling my hair out trying to interface with powershell.  Working query for me (no need to set schema beforehand) was $sql="SELECT * FROM public.""Metrics"""