# "Relation ... does not exist" after deleting few tables

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a postgres **database**, which naming `midgard_dev`. It has a many **tables**.

After **changing** in `models` at `product` app I got error '*Column `product_...` does not exist*'. I **removed** few tables in database, which related with `product`, and got error "*Relation `products_product` does not exist. LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) *AS "__count" FROM "`products_product`*".

This error I get, when open page with `product` (from admin-panel or user-page)

I watched migrations (with `./manage.py showmigrations`) and saw, that all migrations successful.

`makemigrations app` and `migrate --fake` don't help respectively. Delete the entire database don't want.

*The tables that remained associated with the product*
[image: The tables that remained associated with the product]

Thnx for help.

Comment: It is impossible to answer this query without knowing what *exactly* you did and how your queries look. If you drop tables, I'd say that it is unsurprising if you get errors about missing tables...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I don't know the `postgres` well. I do not know how and what information to provide, so that you can help me ... I really do not want to delete the entire database. This error only appears when I try to open pages that are related to `products`...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I deleted the `products_order`, `products_cart`, and other. The last thing I deleted is the `products_product` table (and its associated tables).  After that, an error of this type appeared. Before that there was something like '_Column product_id (etc) does not exist_'

Comment: It seems that the error messages name the problem correctly. Probably the column didn't exist, so either don't reference it in your queries or add it to the table. Don't drop tables you still need. Can you restore a backup? Maybe you should get a programmer to look at the problem.

Comment: Welcome @pythoner. You should provide more detail when asking questions. Here is an example of how to ask this kind of question https://stackoverflow.com/q/36753568/828757

Comment: @Jack If I write `SELECT * FROM public.products_product;` I get `relation "`public.products_product`" does not exist` (or `SELECT * FROM products_product`)

Comment: I will guess there was a delete cascade trigger on the related table. So when you delete the parent table, the children are also deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error, I solved it by typing `python manage.py makemigrations model_name` then `python manage.py migrate model_name` to command promt/power shell. Reason could be that typing same commands without `model_name` do not create tables and/or relations for specific model(not professional opinion).`model_name` is name of your model.