# Heroku flask UndefinedTable relation doesn't exist

Tags: postgresql, flask, heroku, flask-sqlalchemy, heroku-postgres

Application works fine locally, but I am having issues deploying my application on Heroku, getting an Internal Server Error. When I run heroku logs --tail I get this:

```
2020-04-24T22:39:36.957365+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "farm" does not exist
    2020-04-24T22:39:36.957366+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 2: FROM farm ORDER BY farm.name
    2020-04-24T22:39:36.957366+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
    2020-04-24T22:39:36.957366+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2020-04-24T22:39:36.957367+00:00 app[web.1]: [SQL: SELECT farm.id AS farm_id, farm.name AS farm_name, farm.address AS farm_address, farm.city AS farm_city
    2020-04-24T22:39:36.957367+00:00 app[web.1]: FROM farm ORDER BY farm.name]
    2020-04-24T22:39:36.957367+00:00 app[web.1]: (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
    2020-04-24T22:39:36.957668+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.95.177.213 - - [24/Apr/2020:22:39:36 +0000] "GET /farms HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "-" "
-"
```

Also, I am getting this status, not sure if it helps.

```
$ heroku pg:info
=== DATABASE_URL
Plan:                  Hobby-dev
Status:                Available
Connections:           2/20
PG Version:            12.2
Created:               2020-04-24 22:23 UTC
Data Size:             7.9 MB
Tables:                0
Rows:                  0/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow:           Unsupported
Rollback:              Unsupported
Continuous Protection: Off
Add-on:                postgresql-encircled-56224
```

And doing a heroku diagnose:

```
$ heroku pg:diagnose
Report 7834cb14-1b08-4532-b611-4b457e00410e for fsdn-farm-shop::DATABASE_URL
available for one month after creation on 2020-04-25T10:06:21.528717+00:00

RED: Idle in Transaction
Pid    Duration         Query
─────  ───────────────  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
18615  00:20:55.869121  SELECT farm.id AS farm_id, farm.name AS farm_name, farm.address AS farm_address, farm.city AS farm_city
                        FROM farm ORDER BY farm.name
GREEN: Connection Count
GREEN: Long Queries
GREEN: Long Transactions
GREEN: Indexes
GREEN: Bloat
GREEN: Hit Rate
GREEN: Blocking Queries
GREEN: Table Transaction ID Wraparound
GREEN: Schema Count
SKIPPED: Sequences
Error could not do check
SKIPPED: Database Transaction ID Wraparound
Error Database wraparound check not supported on this plan
SKIPPED: Load
Error Load check not supported on this plan
```

Models are set up this way:

```
class Farm(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'farm'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120))
    address = db.Column(db.String(120))
    city = db.Column(db.String(32))

    product = db.relationship('Product', backref='farm', lazy=True)


class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'product'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120))
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer)

    farm_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('farm.id'))
```

It looks like the migration ran, but I am thinking maybe there is something wrong with the database url or maybe there is a circular import. I'm new to this, can't seem to figure this out.

Also including my github:
https://github.com/victorcocuz/fsdn-farm-shop

Answer (score 0):

The error message `relation "farm" does not exist` is being raised by postgresql, not sqlalchemy or psycopg2 (the database driver sqlalchemy uses). The error is telling us that the query the database is getting is:

```
SELECT 
   farm.id AS farm_id,
   farm.name AS farm_name, 
   farm.address AS farm_address, 
   farm.city AS farm_city
FROM 
   farm 
ORDER BY 
   farm.name;
```

but it doesn't recognize the table name `farm` in the schema its searching.

Note the same error in this question: [Postgresql tables exists, but getting "relation does not exist" when querying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753568/postgresql-tables-exists-but-getting-relation-does-not-exist-when-querying)

If your schema is not the public schema, I would try specifying the schema in your ORM by adding this:`__table_args__ = {"schema":"schema_name"}` under `__tablename__ = 'farm'`.

Or you could try `__tablename__ = '{schema_name}.farm'`.

Comment: I'm using SQLAlchemy ORM, I believe it is taking care of this in the background.