# docker postgres don't see tables when connecting from outside

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am starting up a postgres container using the below shown docker-compose.yml.

After i start the containers, the init scripts creates the schemas and tables. If I log into docker container `docker exec -it my_postgres /bin/bash` and run psql, I can see all the tables in the schema.

But if I connect to port 5432 on my local host from a IDE client, login succeeds, I see the database and schema that was created. **But donot see any of the tables in the schema.**

I am not trying to have persistent data. Rather, I want to create the schema and tables everytime the container starts up and access the database from outside the container.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: my_postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=docker_u
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxx
      - TZ=America/New_York
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - '~/myprojects/tmp/docker/create_user.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1-create_user.sql'
      - '~/myprojects/db/events.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2-create_tables.sql'
      - '~/myprojects/db/function.close_alert_using_signature.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/3-function.close_alert_using_signature.sql'
```

I get the following error on docker-compose console

```
my_postgres | 2023-03-20 17:56:50.230 EDT [146] STATEMENT:  select * from sentinus.rest_events
my_postgres | 2023-03-20 17:57:01.409 EDT [146] ERROR:  relation "sentinus.rest_events" does not exist at character 15
```

Comment: check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753568/postgresql-tables-exists-but-getting-relation-does-not-exist-when-querying

Comment: Problem seems be b'cos the I am creating the schema and tables as the root user. Still trying to figure out. WIll post my answer once I find the solution

Comment: okay !! please check if you are able to grant the permission as Marcel suggested on the above link.