# Can't query data from my postgres database in Qt

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am very new to sql (3 days) and im using pgAdmin. Within pgAdmin, I can query any data from any availabe database's as normal, but from Qt after connecting successfully, I can only query data from the default database 'postgres' that I created a table for. Attempting to query data from any other database I created does nothing from Qt. My guess is that it could be an access privilege problem, so I used the grant wizard to grant all access to the table I want to view, but still no luck:

```
                                     Access privileges
Schema |  Name  | Type  |        Access privileges         | Column privileges | Policies
--------+--------+-------+----------------------------------+----------------   ---+----------
public | tTable | table | postgres=a*r*w*d*D*x*t*/postgres+|                   |
       |        |       | =arwdDxt/postgres                |                   |
(1 row)
```

Like I said I am really new and kinda lost with this issue. Any help appriciated. Thanks

Comment: You can only query data from the database you are currently connected to. (pgAdmin uses multiple connections under the hood.) You can use [schemas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022755/whats-the-difference-between-a-catalog-and-a-schema-in-a-relational-database) to "categorize" tables further.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, I did notice before that the other database's status was idle but default was always active but i don't yet understand how to change..