# How can I show the catalogs and schemas in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/17943883/156458

> in both Postgres and the SQL Standard we have this containment
>   hierarchy:
>
> - A computer may have one cluster or multiple.
> - A database server is a *cluster*.
> - A cluster has [*catalogs*][8]. ( Catalog = Database )
> - Catalogs have *[schemas][9]*. (Schema = [namespace][10] of tables, and security boundary)
> - Schemas have [*tables*][11].
> - Tables have [*rows*][12].
> - Rows have *values*, defined by [*columns*][13].

In postgresql, I have a database called `students` and there is a table called `student` under it:

```
postgres=# \c students
You are now connected to database "students" as user "postgres".
students=# \dt;
 public | student | table | postgres
```

I was wondering if database `students` is also a catalog?

Where is the schema between `students` and `student`?

In general, how can I list

- all the catalogs and
- all the schemas under a catalog, and
- all the tables under a schema?

How can I show

- the current catalog, and
- the current schema?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

In shortly, I usually explain to my junior teammate when they starting to research about PostgreSQL.

In PostgreSQL:

- A Database Server is like an Industrial Zone, there will have many Databases-Cluster (Building)
- Each Database-Cluster (Building) have many Databases. Those are like the floors in Building. The Databases is here as you call the Catalogs. Those Databases-Catalogs (floors) are quite independent with each other, you can not using others materials directly, you must use somethings just like stair, electric wire ... (in database is DBLINK).
- Okay, next, each Database-Catalogs have many Schemas, which are like many Rooms on your floors. Those Schemas can use the material from each others.
- Then, each Schemas have many cell elements such as Table, View, Function, Sequence .... All schemas have the same structure.

Now, back to you example:

- students: is Database (which you call Catalogs)
- public: is schema.
- student: is table.

`public | student | table | postgres` is corresponding with `schema | table | kind of table | owner of table`

You can list:

- catalogs (Database) by the command `\l` in psql or query `select * from pg_database;`
- Schemas under a catalog by the command `\dn` in psql or query `select * from information_schema.schemata;`
- Tables under a schemas by the query `select * from pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'Your schema';`

You can show:

- Current Database (Catalogs) by the query `select current_database();`
- Current Schema by the query `select current_schema;`

Please pay attention that PostgreSQL have two system schema call information_schema and pg_catalog, this maybe make you confuse.

The pg_catalog is a system schema. [More information](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/catalogs.html).

> The system catalogs are the place where a relational database management system stores schema metadata, such as information about tables and columns, and internal bookkeeping information. PostgreSQL's system catalogs are regular tables. You can drop and recreate the tables, add columns, insert and update values, and severely mess up your system that way. Normally, one should not change the system catalogs by hand, there are always SQL commands to do that. (For example, CREATE DATABASE inserts a row into the pg_database catalog — and actually creates the database on disk.) There are some exceptions for particularly esoteric operations, such as adding index access methods.

The information_schema is a system schema. [More information](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/information-schema.html).

> The information schema consists of a set of views that contain information about the objects defined in the current database. The information schema is defined in the SQL standard and can therefore be expected to be portable and remain stable — unlike the system catalogs, which are specific to PostgreSQL and are modeled after implementation concerns. The information schema views do not, however, contain information about PostgreSQL-specific features; to inquire about those you need to query the system catalogs or other PostgreSQL-specific views.

I hope these information will help you clearly.

Comment: Thanks. Is `pg_catalog` a system schema or a system catalog? What is it used for?

Comment: @Tim: both of them are system schema which will be exists on each database. I've updated my answer so let check it again.

Comment: If `pg_catalog` is a schema, why is it named `catalog`?

Comment: @Tim: I think you are confusing here. The name `catalog` is the thing you called an unit of database in PostgreSQL. In PostgreSQL we don't have catalog. We call `database`. Maybe somewhere, other person call `catalog` for user from other database system easier to understand. 
We don't have any rule that `database` must be `catalog`.

Comment: what can a database be?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: "We don't have any rule that database must be catalog". So I was wondering what a database can be?

Comment: @Tim: I wonder why you must call `catalog`? What is it? I don't have any definition about the thing that you call `catalog`