# PostgreSQL Namespaces (pg_namespace catalog)

Tags: sql, postgresql

In an effort to find some namespace-like structure in PostgreSQL that's nestable (so not schemas), I stumbled upon this page in the official documentation referencing a catalog to define namespaces in. [Link to documentation page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-namespace.html). It's not obvious to me what a system catalog is in PGSQL, but is this something I can interact with and create namespaces on my own? I'd love to have a nestable name-scoping tool.

Future thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *In an effort to find some namespace-like structure in PostgreSQL that's nestable (so not schemas),*

`pg_namespace` reflects schemas created by `CREATE SCHEMA`, plus schemas created automatically like `pg_toast`, `pg_temp_NN`...which doesn't have any nesting.

There are no nestable namespaces in SQL.

> *It's not obvious to me what a system catalog is in PGSQL*

This question has good answers that might help:

[What's the difference between a catalog and a schema in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022755/whats-the-difference-between-a-catalog-and-a-schema-in-a-relational-database)