# Azure SQL Server: Error occurred during the pre-login handshake

Tags: azure-sql-database, handshake

Occasionally, when I go to connect to my Azure SQL Server through either Power BI or SSMS, I get the following error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
>   error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 121)

There are numerous questions about this topic, but very few address this for Azure SQL Server. My IP address is added to the firewall (and works sometimes!) I have tried increasing the connection time out. I have tried to look at the "netsh WinSock Show Catalog" information as directed by the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315681/pre-login-handshake-woes-with-connecting-directly-to-sql-azure) question, but nothing looked incorrectly formatted.

Has anyone seen any other reason for this error? It popped up a few days ago, went away for a few days, and is back now, but I haven't changed anything in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem ended up being that my computer had disconnected from my company's VPN.

Answer (score 1):

Error 121 has always been considered a network related error as you can read in [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/325487/advanced-network-adapter-troubleshooting-for-windows-workstations) Microsoft Support article. The Internet service you receive, network adapters are things you should consider examine.

> Network connectivity problems have various causes, but they typically
>   occur because of incorrect network adapters, incorrect switch
>   settings, faulty hardware, or driver issues. Some connectivity
>   symptoms are intermittent and do not clearly point to any one of these
>   causes.
>
> Typical error messages include the following:
>
> Error 121: "The semaphore timeout period has expired"
>   (ERROR_SEM_TIMEOUT).

Please consider to click the "Options" button of SQL Server Management Studio, on the "Connection Properties" tab, try setting a greater value for the "Connection time-out" setting.

Comment: Any other suggestions when that doesn't work?