# Microsoft SQL Azure Connection Type failing with TrustServerCertificate=False from MS SQL Report builder

Tags: azure-sql-database, reportbuilder3.0

Using the following connectionstring when setting up a connection to a SQL Azure database from MS SQL Report builder using the Microsoft SQL Azure connection type.

> Data Source=xxxxxx.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=xxx;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;

but getting the following error message

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate's CN name does not match the passed value.)

When using

> TrustServerCertificate=True;

Then the connection is successful.

Looks like the certificate issued by Microsoft Azure is not being trusted by my workstation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/94d24825-c5f7-4fb1-8c9f-a43be3ebde70/connecting-to-sql-azure-using-powerpivot?forum=ssdsgetstarted) you can set TrustServerCertificate=True, setting it to False is just more secure and should help prevent man-in-the-middle attacks. If you set TrustServerCertificate to false then the Encrypt setting should be set to True, but sometimes it does not work due to non-IFS LSPs installed on your computer as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315681/pre-login-handshake-woes-with-connecting-directly-to-sql-azure).

Comment: From a security perspective we want the TrustServerCertificate=False.  Will investigate the non-IFS LSPs route and see if that resolves the issue. We did attempt a Winsock Reset as suggested on the web but that didn't resolve the issue.