# Having problems connecting to SQL Server in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sqlconnection

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server.

I am trying to use the `SqlConnection` object in C#, I've tried putting a domain before my username and I've tried with and without the portnumber

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=username;" +
                                   "password=xxxxx;" +
                                   "server=ipaddress:portnumber;" +
                                   "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                   "database=databaseName; " +
                                   "connection timeout=30");

try
{
    myConnection.Open();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

I don't get any error message, it just hangs at `myConnection.Open`

Comment: Try either just `"server=ipaddress;"`, or if that doesn't work, try `"server=ipaddress,portnumber;"` - separate IP address and port number by a **comma** (`,`), not a colon ...

Comment: You have `Trusted_Connection` set to `yes` but also pass values for the username and password. It's one of the other; which are you really trying to use?

Comment: @Larnu wouldn't that be `Integrated Security=True`?

Comment: `Integrated Security` and `Trusted_Connection` are synonyms, @Filburt: [What is the difference between Trusted_Connection and Integrated Security in a connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3077529/3484879)

Comment: I've removed the Trusted_Connection line as I would like to connect with username and password. I have also tried Marcs suggestions, however it still reacts the same way and hangs when trying to open connection

Comment: why to use Trusted_Connection and use password too,usually I open management studio and copy paste server name like server3\sql2014  or 10.10.10.10\sql2014

Comment: Sounds like the host/application can't reach the specified instance. if it's hanging then it implies you're getting a timeout error, rather than an invalid credentials error. I *assume* TCP/IP is configured and enabled on the remote host, that the firewall port(s) are open (at least to the local host), and that the IP/port is correct in your connection string.

Comment: @Larnu Cool, thanks for the reference! Guess since i started relying on the [Data Link Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10480011/205233) I stopped to care about the nitty-gritty stuff.

Comment: try connection string like this
Data Source=ipaddress:portnumber;Initial Catalog= databaseName;User ID= username;Password= xxxxx;Integrated Security=False;connection timeout=30;

Comment: @Shivani still no luck

Comment: @JoeBW Give the [Data Link Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10480011/205233) a try - it will allow you to troubleshoot your connection issue outside your application and provide a working Connection String once you got it working there.

Answer (score 0):

You try connection string in this format. Please find this link for more info about connection string in c# [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.8)

```
    // To avoid storing the connection string in your code, 
    // you can retrieve it from a configuration file.
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ipaddress;
                                                  Initial Catalog=dbname;
                                                  User Id=userid; 
                                                  Password=pass;");
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already in comments by @marc_s, port# must be specified in connection with **comma**, in your case it should like `server=ipaddress,portnumber;`.

However, [these steps](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/244398/185080) may help you to quickly troubleshoot connection issue with SQL Server